# String substring function

Tags: vb.net, substring

How can i get the string within a parenthesis with a custom function?

e.x. the string "GREECE (+30)" should return "+30" only

Comment: I'd say regular expressions are capable of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some different ways.

Plain string methods:

```
Dim left As Integer = str.IndexOf('(')
Dim right As Integer= str.IndexOf(')')
Dim content As String = str.Substring(left + 1, right - left - 1)
```

Regular expression:

```
Dim content As String = Regex.Match(str, "\((.+?)\)").Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 3):

For the general problem, I'd suggest using `Regex`. However, if you are sure about the format of the input string (only one set of parens, open paren before close paren), this would work:

```
int startIndex = s.IndexOf('(') + 1;
string result = s.Substring(startIndex, s.LastIndexOf(')') - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

With [regular expressions](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Regex+vb.net&form=IE8SRC&src=IE-SearchBox).

```
Dim result as String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("GREECE (+30)", "\((?<Result>[^\)]*)\)").Groups["Result"].Value;
```

Code is not tested, but I expect only compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could look a regular expressions, or otherwise play with the `IndexOf()` function

Answer (score 0):

In Python, using the string index method and slicing:

```
>>> s = "GREECE(+30)"
>>> s[s.index('(')+1:s.index(')')]
'+30'
```