# substring and return the value after a specific character

Tags: vb.net, substring

**"Testing.BSMain, Text: Start Page"**

I would like to substring the value above and returning me only the value after the **": "** in vb.net. How can i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String substring function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082650/string-substring-function)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assumes no error checking:

```
Dim phrase As String = "Testing.BSMain, Text: Start Page".Split(":")(1)
```

which simply splits the phrase by the colon and returns the second part.

To use SubString, try this:

```
Dim test As String = "Testing.BSMain, Text: Start Page"
Dim phrase As String = test.Substring(test.IndexOf(":"c) + 1)
```

Comment: Don't use Split if your original string has more than one ":" or you'll only get back what's between the first to the second ":".

Answer (score 9):

you can use the split method to return the value after the colon **:**

```
   Dim word as String  = "Testing.BSMain, Text: Start Page"
   Dim wordArr as String()  = word.Split(":")
   Dim result as String = wordArr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If proposed solutions don't work for you I did it this way:

```
result= Split("Testing.BSMain, Text: Start Page", ":")(1)
```